# how to use let in $lookup aggregation Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

i am trying to query some data using aggregation but something is not working...

I've been searching some examples and this is what i have...

> ( From my web app i just recieve a searchTerm )

```
 productosModel.aggregate([
        //IN THE FIRST STAGE I FILTER BY REF OR NAME ( searchTerm )
        {
            $match: {
                $or: [
                    { ref: { '$regex': req.body.ref, '$options': 'i' } },
                    { nombre: { '$regex': req.body.nombre, '$options': 'i' } }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: "configtarifas",
                let: { "producto": "$_id" }, //HERE IS WHERE I PRETEND TO DEFINE THE _ID FILTERED 
                pipeline: [
                    {
                        $match: {
                            $expr: { $eq: ['$idProducto',  "$$producto" ] },
                        }
                    }
                ],
                as: "configs",
            }
        }
    ])
```

Then i need to use $lookup to join this collection and add configTarifas to the data, but i would like receive just the documents that match with the _id of the product filtered before...

what am i doing wrong? the config collection is not matching any $$producto... seemns like $$producto is not getting the _id value

Comment: Probably, `idProducto` is type of String, while `$$producto` is type of ObjectId. Just transform it this way: `let: { "producto": {$toString: "$_id"} }`

Comment: @Valijon jesus... what a mistake... yep that is working... add it as solution if you want... thank you !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a mismatched types between parent `$_id` (`ObjectId`) field and `idProducto` (`String`). You need to convert `ObjectId` to `String` with [$toString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toString/) or [$convert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/convert/#exp._S_convert) operators

```
{
  $lookup: {
    from: "configtarifas",
    let: { "producto": {$toString: "$_id"} },
    pipeline: [
      {
        $match: {
          $expr: { $eq: ['$idProducto',  "$$producto" ] },
        }
      }
    ],
    as: "configs",
  }
}
```